# In a Table, how do you make text in a <td> overflow to the corresponding <td> in the next row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a lot of text to input into the details table cell. I want when the text reaches maximum width in the cell, instead of starting a new line in the same cell the text will overflow to the corresponding cell in the next row.

```css
     table{
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    th, td{
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    th{
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
 <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like tabular data to me.

Comment: You can't do that. And @Alohci is right -- numbered list would be the better solution for your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with another `div` inside your cell:

HTML:

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <div class="overflow">Lots of text about lots of things.  Overflow this into the other cell. Lots of text about lots of things.  Overflow this into the other cell. Lots of text about lots of things.  Overflow this into the other cell. 
   </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 20px !important;
  overflow:visible;
  position:relative;
}

.overflow {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

[**Check out this working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/f9859n1v/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it seems like with this method the text isn't formatted properly.

Comment: How are you trying to format it differently? Can you provide an example?

Comment: What I mean is when I applied your solution, my table seemed disorganized. I'm still a beginner so I don't know how to modify it to suit me. I still appreciate the help. This is better than nothing

Comment: No problem.  If you're able to provide an example of part of the problem you're seeing, we might be able to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the table structure.

`display:table-cell;` ensures that the cells won't overlap on each other.

if you change `display:table-cell;` to `display:inline-block;`

And you give it a fixed height/width with `white-space: nowrap;` you will see the intended behaviour. but if you're going to change the display property of the table, might as well not use it.

Working exmaple :

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  display:inline-block;
}

th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Number</th>
  <th>Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```